# Nodejs + Socket.io + Nginx Reverse Proxy Not working

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io

I'm setting an Nginx reverse proxy to a NodeJS app that includes Socket.IO on a server that hosts additional NodeJs apps.

The NodeJS is running via PM2 on port 3001. Here is the Nginx configuration:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name iptv-staging.northpoint.org;
        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

                proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;

                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }
}
```

When running the app via the IP address of the server directly `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3001/` everything runs without issue. Ping/Pong requests from Socket.IO is around 50ms (default pingTimeout is 5000ms). When accessing the app via its DNS name `http://iptv-staging.northpoint.org` the client reports a ping timeout and disconnects. It will reconnect on its first try, then disconnect again on the first ping/pong request.

From what I can tell, the problem has to be related to the Ngnix reverse proxy and how websockets are being routed through. It seems to be that the server's reply to a ping request is not making it to the client. But I can't seem to determine why. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: did you solve the problem? I am having the similar issue with reverse proxy of nginx.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue.  A guy at work provided the answer and in honesty I didn't fully understand, so no credit for me, but I hope I can tease the answers out of my code.

Firstly, you need to tell nginx to send the incoming URI as seen by the client by adding the `X-Real-URI` header :

```
proxy_set_header X-Real-URI $request_uri;
```

The difference between this path and the path eventually seen in your server tells you the base path of the URI.

Then, I created an API endpoint on the server that returns URI info.  This is the key to telling the client what address to use to connect.

```
apiRoutes.get('/options', (req, res) => {

  Log.info('Received request for app options.');

  // This isn't applicable to you, just showing where options declared.
  let options = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(config.get('healthcheck.options')));

  // Decide what port to use.  It might be a port for a dev instance or from Env
  if ((process.env.PORT !== options.port) && (process.env.PORT > 0)) {
    options.port = process.env.PORT;
  }

  // This is the important bit...
  var internalUri = req.originalUrl;
  var externalUri = req.get('X-Real-URI') || internalUri;
  options.basePath = externalUri.substr(0, externalUri.length - internalUri.length + 1);

  res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(options));
});
```

My client is a React app, you'll have think how you need to implement, but here's how I did it.

Here's my 'helper' function for calling the Options service...

```
export async function getOptions() {

  const res = await axios.get('/api/options');

  return res.data;

}
```

In my React page, I then call this when the page loads...

```
componentDidMount() {

    getOptions()
        .then((res) => {
            this.setState({ port: res.port });

        // Call a client-side function to build URL.  Incl later.
        const socketUrl = getSocketUrl(res.port);

        console.log(`Attempting to connect to sockets at ${socketUrl}.`);

        // This is where it all comes together...
        const socket = io(socketUrl, { path: `${res.basePath}socket.io` });
        socket.on('connect', function () { console.log(`Connected to ${socketUrl}`); });

        socket.on('message', (result) => {
          console.log(result);
        });

        socket.on('data', (result) => {
          console.log(`Receiving next batch of results.`);

          const filteredResults = JSON.parse(result));

          // Do something with the results here...

        });

    });

.....
```

Lastly, the getSocketUrl function...

```
function getSocketUrl(port) {

  console.log(`${window.location.hostname}`);

  if (window.location.hostname.toString().includes('local')) {
    return `localhost:${port}`;
  }

  return `${window.location.hostname}`;

}
```

Comment: Thats an interesting approach. I tried it (with some modifications), however the client basePath is returned as "/" on both my laptop (when socketio was working fine) and on my staging server through nginx (where it wasn't working, per the original question). When you implemented this, does the base path change between your development machine and staging (server) environment?

Comment: It does change.  The dev server is a meaningless server name, but with NGinx on Prod, it has a meaningful domain name.  Plus, the Dev server has a port number, whereas Prod does not, or rather the port number is masked by the Prod domain name.  Like you, my original sockets solution was fine on Dev, but couldn’t connect when on Prod.  This is the solution the senior dev used so that sockets would work on either server.

Comment: What’s also worth noting is that there is only one instance of the app in Prod and doesn’t use a port range for load balancing as this add further complexity.

Comment: I tried several combinations of this but wasn't able to get it to work in my environment. Moving to containerize the project with Docker to give it a unique IP and not use a reverse proxy, which should resolve. Thanks for the input!

Comment: Good luck, sorry it didn’t help.

Comment: This answer should have worked but we're missing one piece: in your nginx conf, you need to tell nginx to send the `X-Real-URI` header, it's not a standard header - will edit it...